# Invalid calling Object on IE and - Angular 7 and Spring

Tags: typescript, web, httprequest, angular7, internet-explorer-11

Hi im usung Angular 7 and im getting error "Invalid calling object" when i try to make an http request.
The app works well on Firefox or Chrome but i need to run it on IE because im Using ActivexObject.

Here is the line where the error apears

```
return this.client.get<any>(this.baseUrl + '/api/findall');
```

When i run the app with ng serve it works, but when i build the app and copy the files to spring application resources and generate WAR file, the error appears.
The error
[image]

Regards

Comment: If possible can you please post the picture of an error message? It can give more detail about the error. Are you referencing any JS file in the `Index.html` file? If yes, then it can possible that the file is causing some issue. Also, check whether that file needs to transpilled to support the IE browser.

Comment: I uploaded a picture, and i don't have any script in the index.html

Comment: As we can see in the picture, the error is coming from the `polyfills-es5.js` file. I want to confirm with you whether you are importing the `zone.js` in `polyfills.ts` file? If yes, For testing purposes I suggest updating the `zone.js` to its latest version and see whether it fixes the error.

Comment: yes im importing zone.js in polyfiills and i have tried with the latest version and some old versions but is the same.

Comment: Can you please inform us of which exact versions of zone.js you had made a test? Did you make a test with 0.11.2 or 0.11.3 version? If not, can you please test it and see whether it fixes the error?

Comment: Sure, now im using 0.9.1, i have tried with every version from 0.9.1 to latest version and is the same issue, also i have tried using Angular 8 in a new empty project and it works well but i can´t upgrade the version on my main project. I realized that the error apears on subscribe anything, not only on httpclient.

Comment: You said that error appears on subscribe anything. Do you mean when you include any third-party library or package then this error is coming? If yes, please inform us what libraries/ packages you are including. If I misunderstand anything then please try to correct me.